# Класс матрицы. Транспонирование матрицы. Ошибка сегметации

Tags: c++, указатели, память, матрицы, g++

возникает ошибка сегментации, когда происходит присваивание последнего элемента в первой же строке матрицы

```
RealMatrix tmp(num_rows,num_columns);
for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; i < num_columns; ++j) {
        tmp[i][j] = Matrix[j][i]; // ошибка происходит здесь
    }
}

return tmp;
```

}

как определен мой класс

````
private:
    float** Matrix;
    int num_rows;
    int num_columns;

public:

    RealMatrix() {
        num_rows = 0;
        num_columns = 0;
        Matrix = nullptr;
    }


    RealMatrix(int n_row, int n_col) {
        num_rows = n_row;
        num_columns = n_col;
        
        Matrix= (float**) new float*[num_rows];

        for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
            Matrix[i] = (float*) new float(num_columns);
    
                for (int j = 0; j < num_columns; j++) {
                    Matrix[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

    RealMatrix(const RealMatrix &M) {
        num_rows = M.num_rows;
        num_columns = M.num_columns;
        Matrix = (float**) new float*[num_rows];

        for(int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++)
            Matrix[i] = (float*) new float[num_columns];
        for(int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < num_columns; j++) {
                Matrix[i][j] = M.Matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

float* operator[] (int &index) {
        return Matrix[index];
    }
    const float* operator[](int& index) const {
    // Возвращаем константную ссылку на желаемую строку
    return Matrix[index];
    }

  RealMatrix CalculatingTheTransposedMatrix();
};```
````

Comment: Похоже на опечатку в условии вложенного цикла: `for (int j = 0; i < num_columns; ++j)` -- `j` растёт неограниченно, так как выполняется сравнение `i < num_columns`

Comment: Проблемы начинаются уже с использования сырого указателя для массива из указателей. Сразу делайте массив из `num_rows * num_columns` `float`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите, в

```
RealMatrix tmp(num_rows,num_columns);
```

у вас первым - количество строк, вторым - столбцов. Но ведь и `Matrix` определена так же. Вот и получается, что вы пытаетесь транспонировать матрицу NxM в матрицу NxM же.

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i) {
for (int j = 0; i < num_columns; ++j) {
    tmp[i][j] = Matrix[j][i]; // ошибка происходит здесь
}
```

Но ведь количество строк и количество столбцов может и не совпадать :) Но даже если `Matrix` у вас определена как

```
Matrix(num_columns,num_rows);
```

(из кода это не видно), то все равно

```
for (int j = 0; i < num_columns; ++j) {
```

явная ошибка... Меняете `j`, а сравниваете `i`.  Так что тут уж 100% выход за любые границы...

Comment: боже спасибо... самые ужасные ошибки от замыленного глаза